# Checmarx Issue: The web-application does not define an HSTS header, leaving it vulnerable to attack

Tags: asp.net-core, checkmarx

I am getting the following error in checkmarx (asp.net core application):

*The web-application does not define an HSTS header, leaving it vulnerable to attack.*

Although I have the following code in my app:

```
services.AddHsts(options => { options.IncludeSubDomains = true; options.MaxAge = TimeSpan.FromDays(365); });
```

And:

```
application.UseHsts();
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: do you have any resolution for this?